# Stylus syntax - where do imports come from?

Tags: webpack, stylus, quasar-framework, webpack-dev-middleware

I've got a file called "quasar.styl":

```
@import './quasar.variables'
@import '~quasar-styl'
```

When it gets processed by webpack, using styl-loader, I get this error:

```
failed to locate @import file ~quasar-styl.styl
```

I have this feeling there's something about stylus I don't understand.  Where would it be looking for the file "~quasar-style"?

This file comes from a working boilerplate quasar app, and there isn't a file called `quasar-style` anywhere in the app directories, especially not is node_modules, which is where I gather the tilde tells it to look.

Any ideas?

UPDATE: I uploaded the quasar boilerplate project here:  https://repl.it/@jmbldwn/Quasar-Boilerplate-2

It's not runnable on repl.it because it needs the quasar-cli, but you can see all of the files generated by it there.

Comment: This is most likely related to the `stylus-loader`. Can we have a look at that boilerplate?

Comment: @jim have same issue, after installing quasar and replace the vue generated App, Home, etc. after finishing install it tells me that it cant find the ~qasar-variables-style.styl and ~quasar-styl.styl. did you solve it already?

Comment: I didn't find a solution.  Decided to table the effort in favor of a different UI framework (vuetify) which doesn't depend on it's own CLI.  Maybe I'm old-school.

Comment: I just wasted 2 hours on this.  Obscure naming with no explanations anywhere.

Answer (score 11):

I am using vue3 + vite + quasar
Same problem when tring add quasar to project, after run

```
vue add quasar
```

I just comment out the two lines ( maybe added by vue cli automatically, which is not correct)

in styles/quasar.variables.sass

```
//@import '~quasar-variables-styl'
```

and in styles/quasar.sass

```
// @import '~quasar-styl'
```

And then add quasar main sass import to main.js

```
import "quasar/dist/quasar.sass"
```

And I got fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I just got a fix to this problem, which happened to me when running `$ npm install` in a new clone, followed by `$ npm update`, followed by `$ vue upgrade`.

Note: I had installed the Vue CLI Quasar Plugin version of Quasar, and my `quasar.js` configuration file begins with

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import '@/styles/quasar.styl';
```

#### Solution

1. In your `src/styles/quasar.variables.styl` file, remove the line `@import '~quasar-variables-styl'`, which should be close to the bottom.
2. In your `src/styles/quasar.styl` file, replace the line `@import '~quasar-styl'` with `@import '~quasar/dist/quasar.styl'`.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this error by importing @import url("quasar/dist/quasar.sass")

in my quasar.variables.scss file

```
 It's highly recommended to change the default colors
to match your app's branding.

$primary   : #027BE3;
$secondary : #26A69A;
$accent    : #9C27B0;

$dark      : #1D1D1D;

$positive  : #21BA45;
$negative  : #C10015;
$info      : #31CCEC;
$warning   : #F2C037;

@import url("quasar/dist/quasar.sass")
```